# Can not stop postgres despite immediate stop

Tags: postgresql

I have this issue that is driving me nuts. Despite all my efforts, I am not able to force my postgres server to shut down. I have followed those instructions : http://www.question-defense.com/2008/10/17/pg_ctl-server-does-not-shut-down-force-postgres-to-shutdown

but still, nothing happens and all I got in the shell is

```
waiting for server to shut      down............................................................... failed
pg_ctl: server does not shut down
```

Any help much appreciated.

Update: Checking the logs, I have this recurring error :

```
LOG:  checkpoints are occurring too frequently (25 seconds apart)
HINT:  Consider increasing the configuration parameter "checkpoint_segments".
```

Comment: Did you check the Postgres logfile?

Comment: No (thanks for the advice) quite new to all this. How can I find them ?

Comment: http://blog.endpoint.com/2014/11/dear-postgresql-where-are-my-logs.html

Comment: Ok so I have this reccurring error : LOG:  checkpoints are occurring too frequently (25 seconds apart)
HINT:  Consider increasing the configuration parameter "checkpoint_segments".
Any thoughts ?

Comment: "*Any thoughts*" - you mean apart from the advice in the message? But that should not prevent Postgrse from shutting down actually. There must be something different going on

Comment: Is there any indication in the log that an immediate shutdown request was received? How exactly do you issue the immediate shutdown? How did you start PostgreSQL in the first place? Are you *sure* you're shutting down the correct instance?

Answer (score 0):

After giving it a lot of thoughts especially on the way I installed it at the first place, I realize that I set up the install so the daemon would launch postgres at the start of my machine. Thus, any manual killing would simply result in the recreation of those process by the same daemon.

To resolve this problem you need to stop the daemon from working using launchctl and remove a .plist file in your postgres directory.

Good luck if you face the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably run with the default setting of "checkpoint_segments = 3", that produces the warnings. Your database does many writes, right? It takes some time to write all of this to disk, and your database is quite busy rotating the logfiles, instead doing real work.

If you increase checkpint_segments, you will see performance improvements, and less I/O.

For further readings: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server

Comment: But that still doesn't explain why it's not shutting down (which is the _real_ question)